# How to handle windows authentication using C#, Selenium in newest Chrome version?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, authentication

In newest Chrome version I could not log in using https://user:pass@host/ trick. I have this warning message in console:

[Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

Anybody can help how to handle windows authentication using Selenium and C# in newest Chrome version?

Comment: if the support is removed you can use AutoIT tool to automate this flow and integrate the executable in your existing script.

Answer (score 0):

This what worked for me as I have domain\username for the username authentication:
http://domain%5cusername:password@www.basicauthprotected.com

I got this syntax from here: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/34#issuecomment-191403434

---

Also regarding the support of basic authentication in the URL for Chrome, it is back, and it seems that dropping it was a bug as reported by **mkwst's** comment here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=435547#c33